Is there a way to prevent selenium (java) to download the latest browser and driver?
I have a docker image that is used to run selenium tests. The problem is that selenium always downloads the latest browser (chrome) and driver (chromedriver) leading to a lot of traffic.
I have tried to download chrome and chromedriver using selenium-manager both from the python and java packages in my Dockerfile. Even though the files are downloaded, when the tests run they are downloaded again. I have also tried setting the following env vars in my Dockerfile:
```
ENV SE_OFFLINE=true
ENV SE_AVOID_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD=true
ENV SE_FORCE_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD=false
ENV SE_TTL=0
```

And, finally I tried to set SE_MANAGER_PATH env var and use setBinary in my code. It seems that both the browser and driver are still downloaded every time a set of tests run using the docker image (in particular, a fargate instance).
Any ideas how to resolve this?

If driver is in PATH (environment variable for "webdriver.chrome.driver" set to absolute path of chromedriver) or you specify driver path and browser path it should use that.  The manager should only be used as fallback when no path(s) are provided.  "SE_MANAGER_PATH" is for location of the driver manager.  (I believe it extracts the manager executable to this path...)

it'll also fallback to using the manager when the file's in PATH do not exist.  So I usually check... something like:  thisDriver =  new File(WEBDRIVERSDIR+File.separator+"chromedriver.exe");
setPermissions(thisDriver);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", thisDriver.getAbsolutePath());  (So create the "File" type first then check for existence, permissions, if it's OK, then set the system property.)  And then ChromeOptions use options.setBinary(absolute_path_to_chrome);
